# Пагинация для комментариев с другой страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, комментарии, пагинация

использую этот код

```
    <?php
    // Получаем комментарии нескольких постов с ID XXX из базы данных 
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_in' => XXX, // массив id постов
        'hierarchical' => false, // отключаем дочерние комментарии
        'status' => 'approve' // комментарии прошедшие модерацию
    ));

    // Формируем вывод списка полученных комментариев
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'per_page' => 8, // Пагинация комментариев - по 4 на страницу
        'reverse_top_level' => false // Показываем последние комментарии в начале
    ), $comments);

    the_comments_pagination();
?>
```

для вывода комментариев с определенных страниц. Комментарии выводятся, НО ...

1. Выводятся комментарии всех уровней, как выводить только родительские?
2. Ни как не хочет выводится пагинация, т.е. сами комментарии разбиваются, а пагинация не выводится, в чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Разбивка комментариев на страницы  админке включена, правда там другая цифра

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `get_comments( ['parent' => 0] );`
2. Попробуй указать параметры:

```
the_comments_pagination(
    'total'   => $max_page, 
    'current' => $page,
)
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_comments_pagination

Comment: Спасибо, направление верное)!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге благодаря Мах, он дал верное направление. Сделал такой код, все работает.

```
        <?php
    // Получаем комментарии нескольких постов с ID XXX из базы данных 
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_in' => XXX, // массив id постов
        'parent' => 0, // отключаем дочерние комментарии
        'status' => 'approve' // комментарии прошедшие модерацию
    ));

    // Формируем вывод списка полученных комментариев
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'per_page' => 8, // Пагинация комментариев - по 8 на страницу
        'reverse_top_level' => false // Показываем последние комментарии в начале
    ), $comments);

    if ( get_comment_pages_count($comments) > 1 ) :
        $max_page = get_comment_pages_count($comments, 8, true); //значение должно совпадать с per_page в wp_list_comments (можно ввести переменную, если нужно часто менять)
        $paged = (get_query_var('cpage')) ? get_query_var('cpage') : 1; 
        paginate_comments_links (array(
            'base'    => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
            'total'   => $max_page, 
            'current' => $paged,
        ));
    endif;
?>
```